# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, nonetype

Getting a weird error. This code worked in 1 server I was in, but trying it in other servers gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Desktop/test bot/cash.py", line 32, in background_loop
    await client.send_message(channel, "{} secures the bag. ${} found inside. ".format(x.user.mention, loot))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'

```
client = discord.Client()

async def background_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel("479919577279758340")
    while not client.is_closed:
        loot = random.randint(25,50)
        emojigrab = ''
        emojimsg = await client.send_message(channel, emojigrab)
        await client.add_reaction(emojimsg, "")
        x = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="", message=emojimsg,
                                             check=lambda reaction, user: user != client.user)
        if x:
            await client.delete_message(emojimsg)
            await client.send_message(channel, "{} secures the bag. {} found inside. ".format(x.user.mention, loot))
            add_dollars(x.user, loot)
            await asyncio.sleep(1800)

try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def remove_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) - dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def add_dollars_stolen(user: discord.User, dollars_stolen: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars_stolen"] = cash[id].get("dollars_stolen", 0) + dollars_stolen
    print("{} stole ${}".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars_stolen"]))
    save_cash()

def get_dollars_stolen(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars_stolen", 0)
    return 0

def get_dollars(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower().startswith("?cash"):
            if message.content.lower() == "?cash":
                if get_dollars(message.author) < 0:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "You're ${} in the hole!".format(get_dollars(message.author)))
                else:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "You've acquired ${}! :dollar:".format(get_dollars(message.author)))


client.loop.create_task(background_loop())
```

Comment: you checked for `x` but you didn't check if `x` has a `user` or if it was None.

Comment: Is this happening when users react to the message, or when the bot reacts to the message?  You could make the check `check=lambda reaction, user: user and user != client.user`

Comment: It happens when users react to the message. i added user and user != client user and it gets rid of the error, but it doesn't delete the message and add the new message

Comment: Did you add Patrick's suggestion to the `wait_for_reaction` check lambda (it's different to my answer as it should stop it thinking it has a reaction until it's a valid user).

Comment: Hey, I tried both suggestions. Patrick has helped me before on this because it kept thinking the bot was reacting to the message so he suggested adding user != client.user, but when I add his new suggestion, it gets rid of the error, but it doesn't continue to delete the message and add the new message along with adding value to the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if `x` is defined, but not it it has `x.user` and if that is a valid user object. The error you are getting you is telling you that `x.user` is currently `None`.

You can ensure that user is not `None` by using:

```
if x and x.user is not None:  # or just: if x and x.user
    await client.delete_message(emojimsg)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried before posting this, but when the message is reacted to, it just spits out another "emojimsg " message with reaction.